# How to use Script to set a Netsuite System Field as Mandatory?

Tags: client, field, suitescript

I have a Client Suitescript 2.0 that handles some logic on **fieldChanged** for Sales Order records.
This includes setting some fields as mandatory/non-mandatory according to certain criteria.

It works perfectly, except when I attempt to set a Netsuite System field (such as **'memo'**) as mandatory/non-mandatory.
Nothing happens, and no error.

The code used on all fields is `context.currentRecord.getField({fieldId: 'memo'}).isMandatory = true;`

Does anyone know why this issue would occur, or know of any workaround?

Many thanks!
Giles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var memo = context.currentRecord.getField({fieldId: 'memo'});
memo.isMandatory = true;
```

Comment: O Wow! The seriously worked... I genuinely thought it would make no difference.
Thanks heaps @Brian Duffy!!

Comment: chaining works in most cases but I believe in this case you have to get the field returned as a serverWidget field object before you can set it as mandatory

Comment: yeh that makes sense, thanks @Brian Duffy
I'll keep it in mind whenever I'm accessing an object like that